# Why am I getting this xunicode.sty error in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: luatex

So, I am trying to convert a file into PDF using the LuaLatex package. I am attaching the .tex file as well here. On running the command, `lualatex abc` where `abc` is the name of the .tex file, I get the following error:

```
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded(load luc: /home/user/.texmf-var
/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/lmroman10-regular.luc))

! LaTeX Error: File `xunicode.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

File Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9w02wg03jqnq2n/abc.tex?dl=0

Comment: you have used `xunicode.sty` but don't have it installed (it is in most default installations) you should be able to install it via `tlmgr` or whatever other system you use to manage the tex installation.

Comment: please do not use external links. This question and its answers will be online forever, your dropbox link is probably not. Please make the smallest (complete) example that you can that shows the error and then add it to teh question as a code block.

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu 16.04, I was getting the same error, and after installing various packages, the error went away after installing `texlive-xetex` package (but another package might've also worked to get the required dependency).

Comment: Installing `texlive-xetex` worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 as well.